# Consume json DATA from AMQP with celery

Tags: python, json, celery, amqp, pika

I have a technical problem with network analisys.

Netflow flows is collected by PMACCT and send this flows into rabbitMQ for analysis.
Analysis will be done by a python script, add some field like dns ptr, and other network information.

I have wrote a custom consumer script using pika, but i have poor performance. I have tried to use python-multiprocessing to improve performance, but Celery will be more performant (i guess).

Do you know if i can use Celery to consume this data (sent and serialized by PMACCT)? Data format is a simple JSON object with field (format does not match with Celery task format). Other librairy can help me ?

Final goal is to loadbalance flow analisys over several servers (many Gbytes of flows).

Comment: Celery should be fine, but if you need performance you should look at using librabbitmq with Celery (https://github.com/celery/librabbitmq). Other alternatives would be to use a thread safe library like my own amqp-storm https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm/blob/master/examples/basic_threaded_consumer.py

Comment: Ok @eandersson. amqp-storm is exactly what I am looking for.And can i use librabbitmq with amqp-storm ?

Comment: Nah, they are both AMQP libraries. AMQP-Storm isn't as fast as librabbitmq, but it is easier to work with AMQP-Storm as it is thread-safe, while librabbitmq isn't.

Comment: Hum ok. I'm trying to use AMQP-Storm. Let me check.
And just for information, what does it mean : channel.basic.qos(int) ?

Comment: That is the setting for RabbitMQ pre-fetch. If you have multiple consumers on one queue I would recommend to keep the value low, e.g. 100. https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html

Comment: I have try to used your librairie and i have best performances. Thanks.

But, my program is less performant if i use this function: http://pastebin.com/jgS0JrPF

Redis is used for cache data, and DNS resolution is done to know the domain associated to this IP.
One function of this code is blocking thread ?

Comment: It's possible that you are hitting the GIL (https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) with your code. It is difficult to say exactly why, but you could try to run your code with pypy. It should be significantly faster. http://pypy.org/

Answer (score 1):

*I posted this as comments, but I thought that I would compile it as an answer.*

[Celery](https://github.com/celery/celery) should be fine for handling json data.

As for performance I assume that you are using the Pika BlockingConnection module. This is a very slow implementation and is [crippled with bugs](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues). If you want performance changing to a C implementation of the AMQP library, e.g. [librabbitmq](https://github.com/celery/librabbitmq) should speed things up drastically and an advantage with [librabbitmq](https://github.com/celery/librabbitmq) is that it can be used with [Celery](https://github.com/celery/celery).

The downside with [librabbitmq](https://github.com/celery/librabbitmq) is that it is not thread-safe. There are a few thread-safe alternatives available; such as my own [AMQP-Storm](https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm/tree/master/examples), or [Rabbitpy](https://github.com/gmr/rabbitpy) from the maintainer of pika.